# Two indexes in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to do something like this:

```
<?php
    $times[monday] = ['7-10', '3-5', '1-6'];
    $times[tuesday] = ['5-9', '12-15', '19-22'];
    echo $times[monday][2]
?>
```

This code would echo out `3-5`, because that's the second item in array `$times[monday]`.

However, that just errors out with:

`Notice: Use of undefined constant monday - assumed 'monday' in /var/www/sch/index.php on line 2`

`Notice: Use of undefined constant tuesday - assumed 'tuesday' in /var/www/sch/index.php on line 3`

`Notice: Use of undefined constant monday - assumed 'monday' in /var/www/sch/index.php on line 4`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
    $times['monday'] = array('7-10', '3-5', '1-6');
    $times['tuesday'] = array('5-9', '12-15', '19-22');
    echo $times['monday'][2]
?>
```

You will want to quote the array string element identifier (e.g. 'monday') and make the array multi-dimensional as shown.

Without quotes, the string `monday` is processed as a constant.

Note that the code:

```
echo $times['monday'][2]
```

would echo out `1-6` because arrays are 0 based (elements start at 0). If you want `3-5`, it would be:

```
echo $times['monday'][1]
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the quotes, and to initialize an array, you should add `array` keyword before the parenthesis:

```
<?php
    $times['monday'] = array('7-10', '3-5', '1-6');
    $times['tuesday'] = array('5-9', '12-15', '19-22');
    echo $times['monday'][2];
?>
```

Comment: Is there any downside to doing this?

Comment: Is it possible to use {} instead of [] ?